# Is there a configuration file for Scala REPL / SBT Console?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've been trying to find some sort of a dotfile to put Scala REPL settings and custom function in.

In particular I'm interested in passing it flags like `-Dscala.color` (enables syntax highlighting), as well as overriding settings like result string truncation:

```
scala> :power
scala> vals.isettings.maxPrintString = 10000
```

It would be nice to have these settings apply to both the simple Scala REPL sessions as well as sbt console sessions.

Does such a central configuration place exist for Scala?

Answer (score 4):

Poor man's solution: Set yourself an `alias`

```
alias myScala='scala -Dscala.repl.axPrintString = 10000'
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use a modernized Scala REPL:

https://lihaoyi.github.io/Ammonite/

Comment: Ammonite has some rough edges, but is totally awesome.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Global-Settings.html) `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt` is the global configuration file for sbt. You can change your global settings here, this probably not going to effect REPL but should do work with SBT Console

Comment: I made `.sbt/0.13/plugins/color.sbt` and put this in it: `initialize ~= (_ => if (ConsoleLogger.formatEnabled) sys.props("scala.color") = "true")`

Answer (score 1):

You mainly asked about property settings, this goes a little beyond that to consider loading a definitions file as well—and isn't much help for Windows—but I thought I'd share in case it's useful:

I've resorted to using a wrapper script saved as `~/bin/scala`, to set config properties and load some utility functions:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# The scala REPL doesn't have any config file, so this wrapper serves to set
# some property values and load an init file of utilities when run without
# arguments to enter REPL mode.
#
# If there are arguments, just assume we're running a .scala file in script
# mode, a class or jar, etc., and execute normally.

SCALA=${SCALA:-/usr/local/bin/scala}

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ] && [ -r ~/.config/scala/replinit.scala ]; then
    exec "$SCALA" -i ~/.config/scala/replinit.scala -Dscala.color
else
    exec "$SCALA" "$@"
fi
```

If you sometimes use Ammonite REPL, as another answer suggests, the utility definitions can be shared by `load`ing them from `~/.ammonite/predef.scala`:

```scala
try load.exec(ammonite.ops.home/".config"/'scala/"replinit.scala")
catch { case _: Exception => println("=== replrc not loaded! ===") }
```

I'm not sure about a way to load the init file for `sbt console` automatically, though—[Seth Tisue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86485/seth-tisue)'s comment about the `initialize` setting is helpful for properties, but using a `:load` command in a value for `initialCommands in console` doesn't appear to work.