# Scala REPL: Can I run a piece of code at every start?

Tags: scala, scala-repl

Just like bash invokes `.bashrc` every time it starts, can scala REPL do the similar thing?

Comment: I think you can't. But there is a better alternative, [Ammonite](http://ammonite.io/#Configuration) with much moore goodies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is quite similar to [Is there a configuration file for Scala REPL / SBT Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338866/is-there-a-configuration-file-for-scala-repl-sbt-console). However, depending on your needs you could take into account that the Scala REPL `scala` command in Linux is actually a shell script that calls the Java interpreter with the corresponding Scala JAR files in the classpath.

Depending on your needs (i.e. what you need to set or do at the beginning of the REPL, that might be a place to do something there), you could create a modified version of this script or use another REPL such as [Ammonite](http://ammonite.io/).